# How to user erlang gen_smtp to send html-formatted email?

Tags: html, erlang, smtp, html-email

`gen_smtp` can be found [here](https://github.com/Vagabond/gen_smtp)

What I want is to let the content of email supports HTML tag, such as `<strong>Hello</strong>`

Will display as **Hello**.

Answer (score 2):

See the `gen_smtp` mimemail tests for an example of [`multipart/alternative` messages](https://github.com/Vagabond/gen_smtp/blob/master/src/mimemail.erl#L1738):

```
Email = {<<"text">>, <<"html">>, [
  {<<"From">>, <<"me@example.com">>},
  {<<"To">>, <<"you@example.com">>},
  {<<"Subject">>, <<"This is a test">>}],
  #{content_type_params => [
    {<<"charset">>, <<"US-ASCII">>}],
    disposition => <<"inline">>
  },
  <<"This is a <strong>HTML</strong> message with some non-ascii characters øÿ\r\nso there">>},
Encoded = mimemail:encode(Email)
```

Comment: The sample code as shown did not work for me as it is using map syntax, the version of erlang I am running: Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.0.3] so modern. The fault(?) lies with the mimeencode function not being able to use the map instead it requires a proplist so the actual working code is this:
```
Email = {
  <<"text">>,
  <<"html">>,
...elided for brevity, change here --> 
  [{<<"content-type-params">>, [{<<"charset">>, <<"US-ASCII">>}]},
   {<<"disposition">>, <<"inline">>}
  ],
  <<"This is a <strong>HTML</strong> øÿ\r\nso there">>
}.
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://github.com/selectel/pat. It's an easy to use SMTP client and you can use any text, including html tags as body of the message.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Ward Bekker is fundamentally correct but it took me a while to make it work as the `mimemail:encode/1` expects a `proplist` not a `map` which the example shows.
I used Erlang Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.0.3] and it failed with:

```
** exception error: no function clause matching proplists:get_value(<<"content-type-params">>, #{disposition => <<"inline">>,<<"content-type-params">> =>              [{<<"charset">>,<<"US-ASCII">>}]},[]) (proplists.erl, line 215)
     in function  mimemail:ensure_content_headers/7 (/Users/sean/Documents/code/erlang/scofblog/_build/default/lib/gen_smtp/src/mimemail.erl, line 661)
```

The following is the modified code and the encoded output:

```
Email = {
  <<"text">>,
  <<"html">>,
  [
    {<<"From">>, <<"me@example.com">>},
    {<<"To">>, <<"you@example.com">>},
    {<<"Subject">>, <<"This is a test">>}
  ],
  [{<<"content-type-params">>, [{<<"charset">>, <<"US-ASCII">>}]},
   {<<"disposition">>, <<"inline">>}
  ],
  <<"This is a <strong>HTML</strong> øÿ\r\nso there">>
}.

62> mimemail:encode(Email).
<<"From: me@example.com\r\nTo: you@example.com\r\nSubject: This is a test\r\nContent-Type: text/html;\r\n\tcharset=US-ASCII\r\nCon"...>>
```

Hope that saves some head scratching.